# Why is there a gap between my react-navigation header and the device edge?

Tags: react-native

I am building an app using react-navigation. I replaced the default header with my own custom component

```
const CustomHeader = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Welcome Stranger!</Text>
            <Image
                style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                source={require("./assets/logo.png")}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

styles.header (where deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width):

```
header: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: "center",
        width: deviceWidth,
        borderBottomColor: colors.primary,
        borderBottomWidth: 2
    }
```

However my header component is not aligned right. There is a gap on the left and it overflows on the right. Why is this happening?

[image: Header component with gap]

Comment: My guess is that the parent component is responsible for this. What does the styling look like at the parent level?

Answer (score 0):

Check the styling of the parent component once it may be coming from the parent component.
also, you can inspect the style using the developers option